# Not able to understand how to wrap the index.ts file with provider store

Tags: react-native

I am not able to understand how to wrap the index.ts file with the provider store , someone had worked in this app now i can change the entire flow. So if someone could help me with this issue .
I am working with aws amplify so when i try to logout i am clearing the state but it does not navigate it me to login screen ,

```
  <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={getTheme() as ExtendedTheme}>
        {auth ? (
          <DrawerNavigation></DrawerNavigation>
        ) : (
          <AuthStackNavigation></AuthStackNavigation>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
```

this is my app.tsx file so if the auth is false it should go to authstack navigation and if it is true it should go to drawer navigation.

```
const DrawerNavigation = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{swipeEnabled: false}}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={StackNavigation}
        options={{headerShown: false}}></Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

this is my drawer navigation

```
function AuthStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <AuthStackNavigation.Navigator>
      <AuthStackNavigation.Screen
        name={'Login'}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
        component={LoginScreen}></AuthStackNavigation.Screen>
      <AuthStackNavigation.Screen
        name={'Otp'}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
        component={OtpScreen}></AuthStackNavigation.Screen>
      <AuthStackNavigation.Screen
        name={'afterLogin'}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
        component={DrawerNavigation}></AuthStackNavigation.Screen>
    </AuthStackNavigation.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and this is the authstacknavigation

I just want to know how should i logout and after logout it should take me to the login screen

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

this is my index.ts file

Comment: why do you want to provide the store?
can't you just use / connect to it where needed ? it will be more clean and understandable where it is used.

Comment: hi , because if you check my app.tsx file it's pretty simple if the auth is false it should go to Authstacknavigation and if it true it should go to drawer navigation , so when i try to logout i am clearing the state then auth becomes false , so it should automatically take me to the login screen but App.tsx file does not even load , and to be honest i am new to redux so dont know much about it , if you can explain with an example that would be great .

Comment: context provider was build to provide props to all of its children, i think this is not the case you are aiming for (cuz you don't even pass the `auth` prop to the children). you just need to have a connection to a store in your file. you can check the wix/remx lib to enable easy state management. https://github.com/wix/remx